# Calculate the Bloch wave

Tags: ode, eigensystem, mathematica

The eigenvalue problem 
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+2i k\frac{du}{dx}-[k^2-6\sin(x)^2]u(x)=-\mu u(x)$$

gives the first five eigenvalues with $k=0$ or $k=1$ which are $2.06$, $2.26$, $5.16$, $6.81$, and $7.74$.

And those eigenvalues I have calculated, but the corresponding eigenvector that I got did not agree with Fig.2 in the paper [Z. Shi and J. Yang, "Solitary waves bifurcated from Bloch-band edges in two-dimensional periodic media," *Phys. Rev. E*, vol. 75, no. 5, pp. 056602, May 2007.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.75.056602)

[image]

In this paper the author tells us the vector at the edge is all real, but I calculate it to be complex. Why is there an inconsistency with the paper?

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718422/calculate-the-bloch-wave).

```
PRE75.056602

Clear["Global`*"]
Lx = \[Pi];
k0x = 2 \[Pi]/Lx;
V = 6 Sin[x]^2;
kx = 0;
{eig0, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-D[u[x],{x,2}]-2I kx D[u[x],x]+(kx^2+V)u[x],
                              u[0]== u[\[Pi]]}, u[x], {x,0,\[Pi]}, 3,
                              Method->{"VectorNormalization"->True,
                              "PDEDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement",
                              {"MeshOptions"->{"MaxCellMeasure"->0.01}}}}]

{2.06318, 6.81429, 7.74678},


kx=1;
{eig2,fun2} = NDEigensystem[{-D[u[x],{x,2}]-2I kx D[u[x],x]+(kx^2+V)u[x],
                            u[0]== u[\[Pi]]}, u[x], {x,0,\[Pi]}, 3,
                            Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement",
                                     {"MeshOptions"->{"MaxCellMeasure"->0.01}}}}]

{2.26673, 5.16594, 12.0926}
```

Comment: Are the boundary conditions periodic?

Comment: The boundary conditions are  periodic

Comment: I think that it would be good to add that information to your question. That being said, I solved your problem using Finite Differences and obtained (about) the same eigenvalues and complex eigenvectors.